# List files in Amazon s3 bucket on wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How can I list all the files (links to each file) in an amazon s3 bucket on a wordpress page?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install a plugin to do this for you.

For example, there this plugin that's allows you to put a shortcode on any post/page to show S3 files: http://codecanyon.net/item/wordpress-aws-s3-browser/6470423

Check out the Live DEMO here: http://www.awss3.redwanhilali.net/?page_id=5#